# Is it always correct to use URLs like "./about.html" or "../about.htm" instead of Absolute URLS like /about?

Tags: python, http, url, browser, path

I'm a computer science student. Recently we were tasked to develop a static HTTP server from scratch without using any HTTP modules, solely depending on socket programming. So this means that I had to write all the logic for HTTP message parsing, extracting headers, parsing URLs, etc.
However, I'm stuck with some confusion. As I'm somewhat experienced in web development before, I'm used to using URLs in places like anchor tags like this "/about", and "/articles/article-1".However, I've seen people sometimes people to relative paths according to their folder structure like this. "./about.html", "../contact.html".This always seemed to be a bad idea to me. However, I realized that even though in my code I'm not supporting these kinds of URLs explicitly, it seems to work anyhow.

Following is the python code I'm using to get the path from the HTTP message and then get the corresponding path in the file system.

```py
    def get_http_url(self, raw_request_headers: list[str]):
        """
        Method to get HTTP url by parsing request headers
        """
        if len(raw_request_headers) > 0:
            method_and_path_header = raw_request_headers[0]
            method_and_path_header_segments = method_and_path_header.split(" ")
            if len(method_and_path_header_segments) >= 2:
                """
                example: GET / HTTP/1.1 => ['GET', '/', 'HTTP/1.1] => '/'
                """
                url = method_and_path_header_segments[1]
                return url
        return False

    def get_resource_path_for_url(self, path: str | Literal[False]):
        """
        Method to get the resource path based on url
        """
        if not path:
            return False
        else:
            if path.endswith('/'):
                # Removing trailing '/' to make it easy to parse the url
                path = path[0:-1]

            # Split to see if the url also includes the file extension
            parts = path.split('.')
            if path == '':
                # if the requested path is "/"
                path_to_resource = os.path.join(
                    os.getcwd(), "htdocs", "index.html")
            else:
                # Assumes the user entered a valid url with resources file extension as well, ex: http://localhost:2728/pages/about.html
                if len(parts) > 1:
                    path_to_resource = os.path.join(
                        os.getcwd(), "htdocs", path[1:])  # Get the abslute path with the existing file extension
                else:
                    # Assumes user requested a url without an extension and as such is hoping for a html response
                    path_to_resource = os.path.join(
                        os.getcwd(), "htdocs", f"{path[1:]}.html")  # Get the absolute path to the corresponding html file
            return path_to_resource
```

So in my code, I'm not explicitly adding any logic to handle that kind of relative path. But somehow, when I use things like ../about.html in my test HTML files, it somehow works?

Is this the expected behavior? As of now (I would like to know where this behavior is implemented), I'm on Windows if that matters. And if this is expected, can I depend on this behavior and conclude that it's safe to refer to HTML files and other assets with relative paths like this on my web server?

Thanks in advance for any help, and I apologize if my question is not clear or well-formed.

Comment: This is what I would call an old-school security vulnerability that you don't see often anymore (but this may not be important to a school project). Your server allowing paths like `../` allows a potential malicious user to look at sorts of files on your system that you did not intend to serve via http. It's "safe" in the terms that it will probably work consistently, but with the security vulnerability mentioned.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks, If it's bad for security I would like to remove the vulnerability, the problem is I can't understand where this happens. But I also realized that only the files in "htdocs" which is the public folder in my application can be accessed that way. As soon as I try to access something like "../htdocs/index.html it resolves to "/htdocs/index.html" which is not accessible because my server searches for a resource with the path "$CWD/htdocs/htdocs/index.html" for that URL. Does that mean I'm safe from the aforementioned security vulnerability?

Comment: Looking at your code, I believe you can access outside the bounds of your html with something like `/htdocs/../../../etc/passwd`. One idea is to use [os.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to normalize the path and then check to see if it's outside of the bounds of your http root directory.